# Wanted a function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Conjecture: There is a $\psi$ function of $x \in \Omega$ limited domain of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that

$ | y | ^ {p} + a (x) | y | ^{q} = y ^ {\psi(x)}$

Where $0 <p\leq q$, $y$ is a vector of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $a$ is a continuous function in $\Omega$. If

$j(x,y)= | y | ^ {p} + a (x) | y | ^{q} - y ^ {\psi(x)}$

the problem comes down to imposing conditions on the function $\psi$ maybe the function needs it more  things, but be sure to be continuous so that we can apply the implicit function theorem by deriving in $y$, I choose  such that $j (x, y) = 0$, then I derive $j$ in the i-th canonical direction and playing the resulting expression  of $j = 0$ inside the derivative and I impose that it is different from zero to be able to apply the implicit function theorem but I got there

$(p-\psi(x)) | y | ^ {\psi(x) -2} \ne (q-p) .a (x) | y | ^ {q-2}$

but I still can't see a choice for  psi ...

Could someone interested give a tip or another suggestion to know if I can actually find this psi and see her face?

Comment: What does $y^{\psi(x)}$ mean when $\psi(x)$ is real and $y$ is a *vector*? Did you forget some "norm" signs here?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your first equation was supposed to be

$$
| y | ^ {p} + a (x) | y | ^{q} = |y| ^ {\psi(x)}
$$
which later equations suggest, I'll define $s = q - p$, and $\phi(x) = \psi(x) - p$. Then this equation is the same as
\begin{align}
| y | ^ {p} \left( 1 + a (x) | y | ^{q-p} \right) &= |y| ^ {\psi(x)}\\
1 + a (x) | y | ^{q-p}  &= |y| ^ {\psi(x) - p}\\
1 + a (x) | y | ^{s}  &= |y| ^ {\phi(x)}\\
\end{align}
where $s \ge 0$, $a$ is any real-valued function, and $\phi$ is also real-valued.

Pick $y = \pmatrix{1\\0} \in \Bbb R^2$ to make things concrete. Then $|y| = 1$.

Let $a(x) = -1$ for all $x$. Then the equation becomes
\begin{align}
1 + (-1) \cdot 1^{s}  &= 1 ^ {\phi(x)}\\
0  &= 1 ^ {\phi(x)}\\
\end{align}
which clearly has no solution. Hence, in the general case, your problem cannot have a solution.

Comment: I believe that this $\psi$ function can only be written in terms of x, p, q when the norm of y is equal to the Neperian number

Comment: Suppose that $y = \pmatrix{r\\0}$, with $r \ne 0$, so that $|y| = r$. Then the equation becomes $1 + a(x) r^s = r^ {\phi(x)}$. Picking $a(x)$ to be the constant function $\frac{-1}{r^s}$, the left hand side again becomes zero, and we have $0 = r^{\phi(x)}$, which again has no solution.